# how to hide numbers of bits in php just disply 3 out of them

Tags: php

Hello i want to hide the extra numbers from below upload display form.

I only want that 1.72 should display others should hide.

how to do this ?

```
 - Your Current file size is:1.7289695739746 MB
 I need like this 
 - Your Current file size is:1.72 MB

others numbers after 72 should hide.
```

Comment: How do you currently print the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
round(2.590,2); //output: 2.59
```

OK? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) function:

```
echo sprintf( "Your Current file size is:%.2f MB", $yourSizeVariable );
```

Comment: @fvu Ah, `0` and `.` are just too near.

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's [printf](http://php.net/printf) functions can help you:

```
printf("- Your Current file size is:%.2f MB",$value);
```

The format string is explained [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php), this is the relevant part:

> An optional precision specifier in the form of a period (`.') followed by an optional decimal digit string that says how many decimal digits should be displayed for floating-point numbers.